# How to Quantify Overlap between non-normal Histograms

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say for example I have a dataset below that is skewed far to one side. The tail end of the distribution towards 200 overlaps with another non-normal distribution. If I have a value that falls in the intersection of these skewed distribution, is it possible for me to calculate a statistic that tells me what is my probability of falling into either of the two distribution. Say if my value is 150 and this lies in the overlap of the two, it would have a 30% chance of being part of distribution A and 70% chance of being distribution B. Would  this work for the intersection of more than two distribution?

[image: Right skewed histogram]

Comment: It could be done fairly reliably from data if you have as much data for the "other' distribution. You couldn't guarantee 30% : 70% unless there is enough separation. Specifically, the 70th percentile of one sample would have to be equal to or below the 30th percentile of the other. // For more than two, guarantees would be harder. // If this is a recurring situation and you know the distribution family involved then parameters might be estimated from data to give a cutoff point that might be consistently useful. // I have an idea you've told only part of this story.

Comment: So if one of my histograms has the lower 10th percentile overlapping with the top 70th percentile of my other histogram, it doesn't violate any statistical rules? So I can say my value in that range has a 10% probability of being part of sample A and a 70% chance of being part of sample B? Does that make sense?